# Create material from code and assign it to an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity3d. I have a prefab which contains 6 quads making it a cube. I want to add image textures to different faces of cube.
I am getting images from a web service, so I have to add or change material in the script.
The problem I am facing is, I am not able to find material property in gameObject.

I have tried below code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class shelfRuntime : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject bottle;
    public GameObject newBottle;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
   
            iterateChildren(newBottle.transform.root);
        
        GameObject rocketClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(bottle, bottle.transform.position, bottle.transform.rotation);
        rocketClone.transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        GameObject newBottleInMaking = (GameObject)Instantiate(newBottle, newBottle.transform.position, newBottle.transform.rotation);

        Transform[] allChildren = newBottleInMaking.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
        {
            // do whatever with child transform here
        }
    }
    void iterateChildren(Transform trans)
    {
        Debug.Log(trans.name);
        if (trans.name == "Back") {
            var ting = trans.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        //   trans.renderer.material  // there is no material property here 
        }

        // Do whatever logic you want on child objects here
        if (trans.childCount == 0) return;

        foreach (Transform tran in trans)
        {
            iterateChildren(tran);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    
    }
}
```

How to set material to quads? There are 6 quads inside my prefab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can no longer access some components directly in Unity. You must use `GetComponent` to get the component(`Renderer`) then access the material from it.

```
trans.renderer.material = ....
```

should be changed to

```
trans.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = yourNewMaterial;
```

Finally, when Cube or Quad is created in Unity, `MeshRenderer` is automtatically attached to them not `Renderer`. So, you might get run-time error with `GetComponent<Renderer>()`. Use `MeshRenderer` instead.

```
trans.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = yourNewMaterial;
```

---

**To create Material during run-time:**

```
Material myNewMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
```

The example below will create a Material, assign standard shader to it then change the texture to the texture from the `myTexture` variable before applying it to a GameObject.

```
public Texture myTexture;
void Start()
{
    //Find the Standard Shader
    Material myNewMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
    //Set Texture on the material
    myNewMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", myTexture);
    //Apply to GameObject
    trans.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = myNewMaterial;
}
```

Comment: var temp = trans.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material ;  returns null ,even tho it contains a material (dragged an dropped an image onto quads)

Comment: Your comment is confusing. You can't drag image to quad. You plug the image to the material that is connected to the MeshRenderer of the quad. What problem are you having now?

Comment: when i click my prefab , i have quads ,i drag the image from assest folder  and dropped on respective quads its created material with image texture assigned to it

Comment: I think that your question is not clear. It says "Not able to set material" not "Not able to set color". Then again, `"trans.renderer.material  // there is no material property here"`. This solution showa how to change Material. If color is what you wanted to change then code in your comment above should do it. You are welcome and happy coding. Here is a [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) for new Unity users.

Comment: no i didnt wanted color , i wanted to create material at runtime , 
but i wasnt able to access em ,
by assigning color i am sure i am able to assign color so i would be able to assign image as well ,

Comment: Even though you have already accepted this answer, I want to make sure that it solved your problem. Take a look at the Edit I made. It shows you how to create a Material from script.

Comment: thank you ! i used this ,
               fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/Saket/Desktop/UnityProject/coolShelf/Assets/sample.jpg");
                tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
                tex.LoadImage(fileData);
is this any different ?